# In John 1:1 why is “The Word” used instead of saying Jesus?

Tags: john, kjv

Is there extra meaning or significance in saying “The Word” instead of saying Jesus?

Comment: John didn't write in vacuum. His readers knew of the λογος (The Logos) as a divine being and the intermediary between God and men (See Philo's λογος which was both θεος and Through whom God created everything). The difference is that John had the Logos as uncreated who became flesh (took upon himself created nature) whilst Philo had the Logos as neither created nor uncreated. The Logos of Philo was that of the Greeks and Stoic philosophy whilst the Logos of John was the literal Son of God, the One who was 
called only begotten God (μονογενης θεος) and only begotten Son (μονογενης υιος).

Comment: @RadzMatthewC.Brown - that is a great comment - make it into an answer please.

Comment: This has a HUGE literature - see https://biblehub.com/commentaries/john/1-1.htm for a sample taste.